# Importing a macro template from the app directory

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to import some macros from the `app/Resources/views` directory, but Symfony doesn't seem to find the template.

I tried the following methods, all of them return an error `Unable to find template`.

```
{% import '::macros.twig' as macros %}
{% import '/app/Resources/views/macros.twig' as macros %}
{% import '/app/Resources/views/macros.twig' as macros %}
```

How can I import macros from `app/Resources/views`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. The file name must have an extension `.html.twig` for this to work.